# Where memmap file is located after operation?

Tags: python, numpy, memory, large-data

I have a code of matrix multiplictaion using numpy memmap

```
def test_memmap():
    fA = np.lib.format.open_memmap('A.npy', dtype='uint8', mode='r+')
    fB = np.lib.format.open_memmap('B.npy', dtype='uint8', mode='r+')

    #need to predefine size of result?
    #fC = np.memmap('C.npy', dtype='uint16', mode='w+', shape=(rows,rows))

    # print fA
    # print fB

    #where it stored if not gived filename?

    t0= time.time()
    fC= np.dot(fA,fB)
    print (time.time()-t0)

    print fC.filename
    print type(fC)

    # print fC[12:10]
    # print fC
```

where memmap file fC is located after operation? And how to specify save path?

How can I point where to save fC(not to store it in memory)? can type and size of array be auto detected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although `fC` is an instance of numpy.core.memmap.memmap, 
it isn't associated with any file:

```
print(type(fC))
# <class 'numpy.core.memmap.memmap'>

print(fC._mmap)
# None

print(fC.filename)
# None
```

The reason why `fC` is an instance of memmap is because `np.dot`, like most NumPy functions, tries to return an array of the same type as its arguments. So the [`memmap.__array_wrap__` method](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html#array-wrap-for-ufuncs) gets called. The [`__array_finalize__` method](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/memmap.py#L280) which gets called last, sets the `_mmap`, `filename`, `offset` and `mode` attributes to None.

You can see `__array_finalize__` getting called if you step through the code with a debugger like pdb.

So although `fC` is a memmap instance, it exists in memory only.

---

To compute `np.dot` with the result written to a memmap:

```
fC = np.memmap('/tmp/C.npy', dtype='float', mode='w+', shape=(Arows, Bcols))
np.dot(fA,fB, out=fC)
print fC.filename
# /tmp/C.npy
print type(fC)
# <class 'numpy.core.memmap.memmap'>
```

Comment: How can I point where to save fC(not to store it in memory)? can type and size of array be auto detected?

Comment: You could save `fC` to a npy file: `np.save(path, fC)`, and then read it back into a memmap: `fC = np.lib.format.open_memmap(...)`. The shape is stored in the npy format.

Comment: but the problem is that I need to write data exactly to disk, I can't hold temp result in memory.

Comment: `np.dot`, like many NumPy functions, have an `out` parameter. If you specify the `out` parameter, then the result is written to the array given by that parameter. I've edited the post above to show how you can initialize fC as a memmap, and then use the `out` parameter to have np.dot write directly to it.